# Exception not catch by Try/Catch in PHP

Tags: php, exception

i've try this example :

```
<?php    
try {
    Not_Exist();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php
But the error is not catched :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Not_Exist() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\mysite\public_html\exception.php on line 3

Why? I'm usually using Dotnet. Maybe i miss something.

Comment: That's *not* an exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`error` is not an exception. PHP itself doesn't throw exceptions on syntax errors, such as missing functions. You'd need `set_error_handler()` to "catch" such things - and even then, a custom error handler can't handle parse errors such as this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Exception being thrown in your code. You're simply hitting a fatal error. If you're trying to find a way around fatal errors, this post may be of help. [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

If you're trying to catch Exceptions, something like this:

```
try {
   throw new Exception("Exception Message");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because that is a `fatal error`, not an exception. You're going to want to use PHP's [function_exists()](https://www.php.net/function_exists) method and try something like:

```
try{
    function_exists(Not_Exist);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // error here
}
// run Not_Exist here because we know its a valid function.
```